# API returns a List<T> OR an Object, how can I get both?

Tags: android, json, retrofit

This is the issue. The datasource sometimes returns a **List** while my model of **Fileannex** only has a getter for a simple File-object.

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was BEGIN_ARRAY at line 3753 column 19 path $.documentlist.document[14].fileannex.file
```

Is there a way to get both types from the response with retrofit? I tried tweaking the model of Fileannex but didn't get the expected outcome.

EDIT*******************

This is the "Fileannex". I haven't translated some of the words to english but hopefully you get the idea.

```
@SerializedName("fil")
private File file;

public Fil getFil() {
    return file;
}
```

And this is the ViewHolder class where I bind the data...

```
        holder.mDownload.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String url = "";
            if( mFeedList.get(position).getFilbilaga().getFil().getUrl() != null){
                url = mFeedList.get(position).getFilbilaga().getFil().getUrl();
                Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
                v.getContext().startActivity(i);
            }
            else{
                holder.mDownload.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), "Not found!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: Retrofit will only take in a single object into which it will return the data, even if that object is a list object of type "some other object." Is there any particular reason why your datasource doesn't have a consistent return type? Can you post an example of the two types it returns as well as some code from the object you have made to retrieve the data?

Comment: The return type is either a File which contains a url to a pdf, but sometimes it can be a List<File> which contains url to both a pdf and docx. I obviously can't manipulate the datasource, but the inconsistency seems to be poppin up here and there.

Comment: In that case Giovanni's solution below might work. Certainly worth a shot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `List<T>` actually is an `Object`, I did suggest to just accept an `Object` as input, and after that check wether it is a `List` or `File` instance. Like:

```
Object obj = getFil();
if(obj instanceof File) {
    File file = (File) obj;
} else if (obj instanceof List)  {
    List<File> list = (List) obj;
}
```

Comment: "accepct object as an input?" what do you mean?

Comment: "The return type is either a File which contains a url to a pdf, but sometimes it can be a List<File> which contains url to both a pdf and docx." 

Where you call `getMyListOrFile`, you should treat it's return value as an `Object`.

Comment: Like: `Object obj = getMyListOrFile();` and then use my posted solution.

Comment: Check my edit. I'm not sure we are on the same page. My model still won't let me access the data as a List. I can't not deserialize more than once(?)

Comment: I tried to edit it so it returns List<File> instead, but then the error message gets reveresed (Expected ARRAY, got Object) on the first index position...

Comment: That's the thing, you should return an Object there. Not File or List<File>

Comment: But if I change it to Object, then the if statement (instanceof File) doesn't make sense(?).

Comment: It does. Then you can see if the object value is a list or not.

Comment: Hmm, would you mind editing you post taking in my edit in consideration?

Comment: I tried to implement your solution and the error message went away, will look more into it tomorrow

Comment: A little update, the error message went away because both List and File is  an Object. The problem then is that there is no relation between the Object in the Fileannex and the File model itself, so I can't access the getters for URLs etc.

Comment: You can cast the Object to a list or File, like `File file = (File) object;`

Comment: "com.google.gson.internal.LinkedTreeMap cannot be cast to java.util.List"

Comment: Allright, can you also edit and show me the gson code?

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: I managed to fix this, it's been a side project that REALLY got put to the side the last couple of weeks.